# A* algorithm not working

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I need some help with my A* algorithm. It's not finding a path at all. I thought it was my heap, but I checked and it's not. Could it be my algorithm?I'm using a 2d array to store all the nodes. The array is basically a map and some nodes are islands (i.e notWalkable). So when I get the successors of a node I'm getting all nodes that are not obstacles.

```
public void findPath(Node startNode, Node targetNode) throws HeapFullException, HeapEmptyException {

    Heap<Node> openSet = new Heap<Node>(this.width*this.height);
    ArrayList<Node> closeSet = new ArrayList<Node>();
    int gScore; 
    startNode.gCost = 0;
    startNode.hCost = getDistance(startNode,targetNode);
    openSet.add(startNode);

    while(!openSet.isEmpty()){

        Node current = openSet.removeFirst();
        if(current == targetNode){
            break;
        }

        closeSet.add(current);
        ArrayList<Node> successors = getNeighbours(current);

        for (int i=0;i<successors.size();i++){
            Node successor = successors.get(i);
            if (closeSet.contains(successor)){
                continue;
            }
            gScore = current.gCost + getDistance(current,successor);
            if (!openSet.contains(successor)){
                openSet.add(successor);
            }
            else if (gScore >= current.gCost){
                continue;
            }
            successor.parent = current;
            successor.gCost = gScore;
            successor.hCost = getDistance(successor,targetNode);
        }

    }

}
    private ArrayList<Node> getNeighbours(Node node) {
  ArrayList<Node> neighbours = new ArrayList<Node>();
  int x = node.gridX; 
  int y = node.gridY; 
  int[][] positions = {{x-1,y+1}, {x-1,y},{x-1,y-1},{x,y+1},{x,y-1},{x+1,y+1}, {x+1,y},{x+1,y-1}};
  for (int i=0 ; i < 8; i ++){
      if(positionExists(positions[i][0],positions[i][1])){
          if (map[positions[i][1]][positions[i][0]].walkable){
              neighbours.add(map[positions[i][1]][positions[i][0]]);

          }
      }
  }
 return neighbours;
}
```

getDistance() is just using the distance formula.

Comment: first I would post the inputs. Make sure there is a path

Comment: I have a map that gets printed and theres always a path

Comment: where is getNeighbours(...)?

Comment: say start is target node. There is a path. How do you know it succeeded?

Comment: What exactly do you see? Endless loop? Or does it ends without reaching the target? Could you log coordinates of the each `current` on every iteration? I think that might provide you with insights on what's going wrong

Comment: I did a small test replacing your `Heap<Node>` with a standard `PriorityQueue` and it worked for me fine at least in the simple cases. So probably you should provide us your bad test data.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluating the trivial case: start node equals target node, findPath will provide no information at all. openSet will be empty and closeSet too.

Comment: startNode and targetNode will never be the same nor will they ever have the same position in the array.

Comment: Well that is new information and that does not preclude that targetNode is an island which it will have no path. So I would post he inputs that you are using. Logging off for then night

Comment: log off and never come back useless